# Does we need a delay time between command in Linux ?

Tags: shell-script, error-handling, delay

I have a script process.csh for processing many files through many steps which the above output is the input of below command. Do I need to insert a delay between commands to be sure there is no potential error of the process in reality ?

```
sed -i.bak -e '1488,2627d' FF_3p63_0p99_m040c.lib    
sed -i.bak -e '1488,2627d' FF_3p63_0p99_p125c.lib
sed -i.bak -e '1488,2627d' SS_2p97_0p81_m040c.lib
sed -i.bak -e '1488,2627d' SS_2p97_0p81_p125c.lib
sed -i.bak -e '1488,2627d' TT_3p30_0p90_p025c.lib
sed -n '2716,3855p' FF_3p63_0p99_m040c.lib.bak | sed 's/_V/_H/g' > FF_3p63_0p99_m040c.split                                                                             
sed -n '2716,3855p' FF_3p63_0p99_p125c.lib.bak | sed 's/_V/_H/g' > FF_3p63_0p99_p125c.split
sed -n '2716,3855p' SS_2p97_0p81_m040c.lib.bak | sed 's/_V/_H/g' > SS_2p97_0p81_m040c.split
sed -n '2716,3855p' SS_2p97_0p81_p125c.lib.bak | sed 's/_V/_H/g' > SS_2p97_0p81_p125c.split
sed -n '2716,3855p' TT_3p30_0p90_p025c.lib.bak | sed 's/_V/_H/g' > TT_3p30_0p90_p025c.split
sed '1487r FF_3p63_0p99_m040c.split' FF_3p63_0p99_m040c.lib > ./temp/FF_3p63_0p99_m040c.lib
sed '1487r FF_3p63_0p99_p125c.split' FF_3p63_0p99_p125c.lib > ./temp/FF_3p63_0p99_p125c.lib
sed '1487r SS_2p97_0p81_m040c.split' SS_2p97_0p81_m040c.lib > ./temp/SS_2p97_0p81_m040c.lib
sed '1487r SS_2p97_0p81_p125c.split' SS_2p97_0p81_p125c.lib > ./temp/SS_2p97_0p81_p125c.lib
sed '1487r TT_3p30_0p90_p025c.split' TT_3p30_0p90_p025c.lib > ./temp/TT_3p30_0p90_p025c.lib
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there’s no need to insert delays, they won’t have any effect on potential errors.

You should however check for errors — the simplest way to do so on current systems is to add

```
set -e
```

at the start of your script. See [David Pashley’s guide to writing robust shell scripts](https://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/). Note however that `set -e` isn’t a panacea, there are [subtle differences in behaviour depending on the shell you’re using](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/).

Comment: There's a hint in the question that this is `csh`. Would `set -e` apply?

Comment: @glenn silly me, indeed, it wouldn’t. Is there a `csh` equivalent?